# Java Pattern to match any sequence of characters except a given list

Tags: java, regex

How do I write a Pattern (Java) to match any sequence of characters except a given list of words?

I need to find if a given code has any text surrounded by tags like  besides a given list of words.
For example, I want to check if there are any other words besides "one" and "two" surrounded by the tag .

```
"This is the first tag <span>one</span> and this is the third <span>three</span>"
```

The pattern should match the above string because the word "three" is surrounded by the tag  and is not part of the list of given words ("one", "two").

Comment: Do you recognize that there is such an essential difference between your question now vs. before your edit, that anyone answering it before your edit essentially wasted their time? Try to be absolutely clear from the start next time. No one here has a crystal ball or can read your mind.

Answer (score 8):

Look-ahead can do this:

```
\b(?!your|given|list|of|exclusions)\w+\b
```

Matches

- a word boundary (start-of-word)
- not followed by any of "your", "given", "list", "of", "exclusions"
- followed by multiple word characters
- followed by a word boundary (end-of-word)

In effect, this matches any word that is not excluded.

Answer (score 4):

This should get you started.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

// >(?!one<|two<)(\w+)/
// 
// Match the character “>” literally «>»
// Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?!one|two)»
//    Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «one»
//       Match the characters “one<” literally «one»
//    Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «two»
//       Match the characters “two<” literally «two»
// Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\w+)»
//    Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.) «\w+»
//       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
// Match the characters “/” literally «</»
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(">(?!one<|two<)(\\w+)/");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        matchList.add(regexMatcher.group(1));
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: I think you might want to change the "one" and "two" in the pattern to "one<" and "two<" so you can still match things that start with either of those.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
if (!Pattern.matches(".*(word1|word2|word3).*", "word1")) {
    System.out.println("We're good.");
};
```

You're checking that the pattern does *not* match the string.

Comment: Thanks for you response but this will not work. I added more information to the description of the problem.